# Spring data DynamoDB pagination issue

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

Spring data dynamoDB is not using the Page object to fetch the results from dynamoDB. Spring data loads the data into memory and then processes the pages out of it and provides the desired page result.

Here is the open issue:
https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/issues/232

DynamoDB doesn't support accessing random page result. It can only provide sequential access.

Even-though I need pagination, due to the above reason, I am not able to use Spring data because I do not know how much amount of data (KB/MB's) Spring loads into memory from dynamoDB. The more data you load at once, the more RCU's will be used by dynamoDB.

I need the information on **how much data does Spring reads into memory**? So that I would like to re-evaluate if I want to use Spring data or not.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually depends on the DynamoDB mapper configuration. From what I can tell, all DynamoDBMapper results from a query or scan are paginated. See the below excerpt:

"A DynamoDBMapperConfig.PaginationLoadingStrategy enumeration value—Controls how the mapper instance processes a paginated list of data, such as the results from a query or scan:

LAZY_LOADING—the mapper instance loads data when possible, and keeps all loaded results in memory.

EAGER_LOADING—the mapper instance loads the data as soon as the list is initialized.

ITERATION_ONLY—you can only use an Iterator to read from the list. During the iteration, the list will clear all the previous results before loading the next page, so that the list will keep at most one page of the loaded results in memory. This also means the list can only be iterated once. This strategy is recommended when handling large items, in order to reduce memory overhead.

If you do not specify a pagination loading strategy for your mapper instance, the default is LAZY_LOADING."

See full docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptionalConfig.html

Comment: I dont think it answers my question. 
You are talking about the loading strategy for dynamoDB mapper. Do you know Spring uses DynamoDBMapper? Do you know Spring uses one of these strategies to communicate? Do you know how much each of the above strategy loads into memory? (follow-up questions)

Comment: 1) Yes, Spring-Data-DDB is using the DynamoDBMapper.
https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/blob/master/src/main/java/org/socialsignin/spring/data/dynamodb/core/DynamoDBOperations.java
2) It has to be using one of these strategies... and you can most likely configure it to use what you need...
3) No but if you're concerned about memory usage then go for the ITERATION_ONLY. That's what the docs say.

Comment: @Deepak If you believe I have provided you the answers to how the queries are managed through Spring-Data-DDB and how results are being read into memory, please mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me start with what I should know to dig further

Answer (score 0):

I have explored few more details related to DynamoDB and Spring-data.

When pagination is asked for Spring-data-dynamoBD (lets assume your strategies are one of these : LAZY_LOADING, ITERATION_ONLY):

- Spring loads a page of data into memory
- The page size is 1MB.
- For LAZY_LOADING strategy, it first loads 1MB of data and if that data doesn't have your requested page of records, then spring-date requests for another 1MB of records and so on... But the previous records that were loaded into memory were not discarded.
- In ITERATION_ONLY, unlike LAZY_LOADING, it discards the previously loaded records from the memory. This way you do not load up your memory and get into performance issues.

Knowing Spring-data loads 1 MB of data helped me move forward.